# copying program arguments to a whitespace separated std::string

Tags: c++

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where I would like to copy all of program arguments in to a string separated by a whitespace " ". i.e., if my program is called as `foo.exe \Program Files`, then my `folder` string below would contain `\Program Files`

Below is an example of what I'm doing now. I was wondering if there was a shorter or easier method of doing this. Is there an easy way to eliminate the `std::wstringstream` variable?

```
int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    std::wstringstream f;
    std::copy( argv + 1,
               argv + argc,
               std::ostream_iterator< std::wstring, wchar_t >( f, L" " ) );
    std::wstring folder = f.str();

    // ensure the folder begins with a backslash
    if( folder[ 0 ] != L'\\' )
        folder.insert( 0, 1, L'\\' );

    // remove the trailing " " character from the end added by the std::copy() above
    if( *folder.rbegin() == L' ')
        folder.erase( folder.size() - 1 );

    // ... 
}
```

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: The usual way to handle paths with spaces is to put them in quotes on the command line. Your program will then see the path-with-spaces as a single entry in `argc`, so you don't need to do any of this special handling. You might be trying to do this as a service to your users, but what if you wanted to add a command line option later?

Comment: I'll note that for my accepted solution below, Thomas's comment is essential.  You MUST double-quote any arguments (paths) that have spaces/whitespace in them.  The double-quotes will not be present inside your program however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string path;
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Not enough arguments" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    path = argv[1]; // Assignment works from char* types
    // Do the rest of your folder manipulation below here
}
```

That should work.  Even with the main() function declared as it is now, it should still work from a TCHAR (I think), or you can change main's declaration to a more "standard" main() declaration.

Answer (score 0):

> if my program is called as `foo.exe \Program Files`, then my folder string below would contain `\Program Files`

And when your program is called with *two distinct arguments* `foo arg1 arg2`, then you want the string to be `arg1 arg2`, too?

The usual way to handle this is to call the program properly in the first place:

```
foo "\Program Files"
```

This will make `argv[1]` contain `"\Program Files"`.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice Thomas's comment - his point is a very important one.

Now, you could find the length of your arguments and make them into one string with that size, as so (note my c++ syntax might be a little off, but the concept is there :) )

```
int length = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    length += strlen(argv[i]);
}
// now add one for each require space
length += argc-2;

char* fullString = new char[length];
int ptr = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    int strlen = strlen(argv[i]);
    for(int j = 0; j < strlen; j++) {
        fullString[ptr] = argv[i][j];
        ptr++;
    }
    fullString[ptr] = ' ';
    ptr++;
}
```

Comment: This has a `C++` tag, so why don't you use `std::string` instead of manually fiddling with character buffers? (And even in the C std lib there's functions to copy strings. No need to brew your own ones.)